# Remove tokenized string from URL and return

Tags: javascript

Code I'm implementing is trying to modify a URL by removing series of numbers and letters if available. What am I missing?

```
function removeToken() {
      let tokenUrl = "https://www.example.com/pathone/pathtwo/8943d932fee15d8be922d1f51f68c0bf3f929824fd48cda8299144861d214c3e/summary";
      let regex = new RegExp("/(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*");// if url matches anything like 8943d932fee15d8be922d1f51f68c0bf3f929824fd48cda8299144861d214c3e
      if (regex.test(tokenUrl)) {
          tokenUrl = tokenUrl.replace("/(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*", ''); //remove anything like /8943d932fee15d8be922d1f51f68c0bf3f929824fd48cda8299144861d214c3e from URL
          return tokenUrl; // desired return https://www.example.com/pathone/pathtwo/summary
      } else {
          return tokenUrl;
      }
    }
```

Comment: For starters, what are you getting instead?

Comment: @caTS i'm getting undefined

Comment: How are you using it? It should not be able to return undefined.

Comment: @caTS Nothing returns or prints to the console. I did get undefined in some online code tester but JSfiddle and codepen returns nothing.

Comment: Really? I get something [with jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0nurLo8/).

Comment: @caTS you're right. I had some additional code interference

Comment: Your regex is inside of a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the regex directly without the class constructor works for me

```
function removeToken() {
let tokenUrl = "https://www.example.com/pathone/pathtwo/8943d932fee15d8be922d1f51f68c0bf3f929824fd48cda8299144861d214c3e/summary";
let regex = /\/(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*/  // if url matches anything like 8943d932fee15d8be922d1f51f68c0bf3f929824fd48cda8299144861d214c3e
if (regex.test(tokenUrl)) {
    tokenUrl = tokenUrl.replace(regex, ''); //remove anything like /8943d932fee15d8be922d1f51f68c0bf3f929824fd48cda8299144861d214c3e from URL
    return tokenUrl; // desired return https://www.example.com/pathone/pathtwo/summary
} else {
    return tokenUrl;
}
}
```

You can also make it a bit more dry

```
function removeToken() {
    let tokenUrl = "https://www.example.com/pathone/pathtwo/8943d932fee15d8be922d1f51f68c0bf3f929824fd48cda8299144861d214c3e/summary";
    let regex = /\/(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*/ 
    return tokenUrl.replace(regex, ''); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mistake most people make, I do it alot too.

You put the regex `/(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*` inside a string, and also forgot a `/`.

I've also cleaned the code, removed unnecessary code, and fixed a couple other mistakes.

Here's the fixed code:

```js
function removeToken() {
  let tokenUrl = "https://www.example.com/pathone/pathtwo/8943d932fee15d8be922d1f51f68c0bf3f929824fd48cda8299144861d214c3e/summary";
  let regex = new RegExp(/(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d\/]*/gi);
  if (regex.test(tokenUrl)) {
    tokenUrl = tokenUrl.replace(/(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d\/]*/gi, 'summary');
    return tokenUrl;
  }
  return tokenUrl;
}
console.log(removeToken());
```